# JkMount different URIs to same application name

Tags: glassfish, mod-jk

On two servers(serverA, serverB) I have Glassfish with application A. In front of them is Apache using mod_jk. Apache responds to domain www.myDomain.com.

How do I do this type of redirect:

- www.mydomain.com/A goes to serverA/A
- www.mydomain.com/B goes to serverB/A

Comment: Basically I want to know how to mount the same application name on two different application servers